# React native webview - this.webview doesn't exist

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am pretty new to react-native. Currently, I am developing an app with react native web-view.

My requirement is to open external links of the app in a chrome tab. To achieve that I used the following code.

```
  <WebView
    source={{uri: catalog_url}}
    onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
      if (!event.url.includes(home_url)) {
        this.WebView.stopLoading()
        Linking.openURL(event.url);
      }
    }}
  />
```

But I found that the highlighted line is not working currently.

Any reference to **this.WebView** line gives an error saying

```
this.WebView doesn't exist.
```

I need an alternative to **this.WebView**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference of this webview. First, you must assign a reference like that.

```
  <WebView
    ref={webview => this.WebView = webview}
    source={{uri: catalog_url}}
    onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
      if (!event.url.includes(home_url)) {
        this.WebView.stopLoading()
        Linking.openURL(event.url);
      }
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have missed the **ref** props from the WebView component

### Solution

```
<WebView
  ref={(ref) => (this.WebView = ref)}
  source={{ uri: catalog_url }}
  onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
    if (!event.url.includes(home_url)) {
      this.WebView.stopLoading();
      Linking.openURL(event.url);
    }
  }}
/>
```

If you need more reference about how to use WebView in RN visit [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-react-native-webview/)

Comment: Did you copy my answer? :)

Comment: @İlker adding reference for webview is same :)  LOL